# How can I root the Huawei Ascend Y530 U051?

Tags: rooting

Which Root Tool Do I Need for my [Huawei Ascend Y530 U051](http://www.gsmarena.com/huawei_ascend_y530-6103.php)?

I have tried kingoroot, one-click, towelroot, z4root, universal-root and none of them work. I'm on Android 4.3 and I'm desperate to root it. I have been googling and watching pointless youtube videos on it and still cant find a root tool that works.

Can you help me to accomplish that?

Comment: Have you already tried Sigma for rooting?

Comment: Have you looked through the whole thread [http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2754481](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2754481). Post #6 has a link to unlocking bootloader, plus a lot more info on other posts.

Comment: unlock your bootloader and towelroot will work